# how to set default prefix for routing in CakePHP 3?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using prefixes for languages, I am not sure this is the right way, but I don't want to write custom routes for each of my controllers. I have 20 controllers by now (most simple).

I have the problem that /nl/contact and /en/contact are trying to route to nl_index() and en_index(), which is fine for admin routing, but all controllers were programmed multi-lingually and using i18n, so they should use just index(), edit(), etc and not language_ in front of it.

How can this be done? The reason I added these prefixes is that I can use the same controller and functions for more content. I am currently writing Configure.write language in beforeFilter for the languages based on first 2/3 characters of the url (/en, /nl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will present you implementation in `Croogo CMS` based on CakePHP

[here is class <s>`CroogoRouter`</s> Router](https://github.com/croogo/croogo/blob/master/Core/src/Router.php)

look at this line:

```
Router::connect('/:locale/:controller/:action/*', array(), array('locale' => '[a-z]{3}'));
```

This will create `Localized routes` pattern, where `locale` variable can be **3 letter language code** ([read in ISO 639](http://www.sil.org/iso639-3/codes.asp))

so that means, if any of parsed path will begin with `3 letter code` it will be used as `locale` variable passed to AppController

Then [look at this file](https://github.com/croogo/croogo/blob/master/Core/src/Router.php), where is presented usage of such class:

```
CroogoRouter::connect('/', array('controller' => 'nodes', 'action' => 'promoted'));
```

as you can see, you will connect some `action path` (here `/`) to controller and action, but CroogoRouter will take care of Localizing this path with `:locale` variable

Note: Don't forget about mentioning **MIT license**, which is default for **Croogo CMS** if you are going to use its code ;-)

Comment: Small world. I was on your site 5 months ago to see good implementation of multiple languages and even bookmarked it for that reason. I used Croogo for 3 months, but stopped using it though. I will try and implement the Croogo router the way you said.

Comment: If I were you, I would prefer to take inspiration from Croogo CMS class CroogoRouter, and make your own implementation which will fit your needs. But anyway, small world, you're right .)